# I need to ungzip/regzip a file for edit in my c++ in windows

Tags: c++, windows, gzip

I'm working on a small application that parses a certain file, un-encrypts, makes changes, re-encrypts, and saves. It works well, but for it to work I need to manually ungzip it, run the application on the output, then gzip what comes from that.  I'm just wondering if someone knows of an elegant solution/library I can use to automate both stages within the C++ application that will run on windows.  Bonus points if it can detect if the file is gzipped in the first place.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) does that.  And [CGZip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cgzip.aspx) implements a C++ wrapper for it.  And [here](http://dotnetperls.com/gzip-test) is an example of how to detect if a given file is gzipped.

> Testing GZIP files
>
> First, we should reference the "RFC 1952 GZIP File Format Specification Version 4.3". This is the document shown in the screenshot. It contains useful information about the file structure of GZIP files. It states that the first two bytes contain fixed values:
>
> ID1 (IDentification 1)
>
> ID2 (IDentification 2)
>
> These have the fixed values ID1 = 31 (0x1f, \037), ID2 = 139 (0x8b, \213),
> to identify the file as being in gzip format.

Comment: It's Saturday and I get a response in 8 minutes. What a great site.  Thanks a lot!